# Get Current User URI for Lync 2013 via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, lync-2013

I'm am trying to get the current user's URI that is signed into Lync on the machine the PS script is run on. I've Googled to no avail. One method I thought of trying was to get the Windows logged in name and then parse that into an e-mail address but there will be instances in which this won't give the correct URI. Is this achievable?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question but a workaround I've found is to get the AD user that's logged in and then retrieve their e-mail address and then use that as their URI.

Comment: You'd likely need to download the Lync 2013 SDK and import that as a module in PowerShell.  I have no idea if what you want to do is actually exposed, however.  Examples [here](http://trevorsullivan.net/2014/06/26/automating-the-lync-client-with-powershell/) and [here](http://blog.powershell.no/2013/08/08/automating-microsoft-lync-using-windows-powershell/).  There does appear to be a `uri` property referenced in the first article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question...

1) Getting sip-address for current user using the ActiveDirectory-module.

```
(Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME -Properties msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress).'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress'
```

2) Getting sip-address for current user using DirectorySearcher.

```
$filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(SamAccountName=$env:USERNAME))"
$property = 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress'

$domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.SearchRoot = $domain
$Searcher.PageSize = 1000
$Searcher.Filter = $Filter
$Searcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($property) | Out-Null

# Value
($Searcher.FindAll()).Properties[$property]
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you putting in both methods.

Comment: Glad I could help! And yeah I figured if it's to be run on a regular user PC odds are they won't have the AD module installed.

Comment: It's funny, I Google'd this just now and came across my own question. Problem is, I'm looking for an example in a different language. Do you happen to know how to achieve the same in C#?

Comment: You can also get it from registry:
`(Get-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync -Name ServerSipUri).ServerSipUri`