# query AD using powershell version 2

Tags: powershell

We have mixed desktop operating systems consisting of windows 7 and windows 10. I have a login script that gathers various information from a powershell script that runs each time a user logs in. The windows 7 powershell is only version 2 which means I cannot use get-aduser, I am therefore challenged to query this information out of AD using a different method that would be compatible with both win7 and win10. I have this line of code that does not use get-aduser and successfully produces a list of all AD users on powershell 5(win10), however when I attempt to use it on powershell 2 it produces the error below.
My questions are these:

1. What do I need to change to get the script working on powershell version2 ?
2. How can I get it to output the current user as opposed to all the users in AD

thank you for any help in advance

```
<position> : The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection: "Configuration system failed t
o initialize".
At line:1 char:1
+  <<<< (New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher "ObjectClass=user").FindAll() | Select-object -property path
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator
```

```
(New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher “ObjectClass=user”).FindAll() | Select-object -property path
```

Comment: For 2, change your query to something like `(New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher "(&(ObjectClass=user)(SamAccountName=$env:USERNAME))").FindOne() | Select-object -property path`

Comment: that works on powershell 5 and returns the name of the logged in user. If I wanted extension attribute1 instead of the username I assume I should be able to swap out the USERNAME part of your script ? Unfortunately it returns an error on powershell version2. May I post the error here ?

Comment: `Exception calling "FindOne" with "0" argument(s): "An operations error occurred.
"
At line:1 char:111
+ (New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher "(&(ObjectClass=user)(SamAccountName=$env:USERNAME))").FindOne <<<< (
) | Select-object -property path
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

Comment: @notjustme
I have also tested another similar alternative syntax on powershell 2 and the errors seem to be the same:
`([adsisearcher]'(&(objectClass=group)(!(member=*)))').FindAll()`
 
 
`Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "An operations error occurred.
"
At line:1 char:62
+ ([adsisearcher]'(&(objectClass=group)(!(member=*)))').FindAll <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

is there some kind of authentication failure to AD happening on powershell 2 ?

Comment: As for extensionAttribute1 you'd have to do something like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28582553/3515885), but where you change `$property = 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress'` out to `$property = 'extensionAttribute1'` (and yes, this should also fail in the same fashion for your case with PS 2.0).

Comment: Make sure you using the correct **`"ObjectClass=user"`** quotes and *not* `“ObjectClass=user”` (please correct this in your question if this is not the issue). To exclude any other issue with your Windows 7 machine (*or any issue with transferring the script, with could explain the incorrect double quotes*), you can start a PowerShell version 2 host on the Windows 10 machine with the command: `PowerShell -Version 2`

Comment: It appears my orginal posting has been updated, thank you for doing that. My apologies for not posting a more clear description originally. I did test his code on both these powershell versions:
1) PSVersion                      5.1.18362.628
2) CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.9148
The code works fine on powershell version 5.x, however the error I have reported is delivered by version 2.x
Could this be an issue with authentication to AD ?

Comment: I have tried this code on both versions of powershell and it also fails on powershell version 2.0

`$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([adsi]"LDAP://dc=XXXX,dc=XXX,dc=uk","(objectCategory=User)")
$searcher.FindAll()`

ERROR MESSAGE:

`FindAll : The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection: "Configuration system failed to i
nitialize".
At line:1 char:18
+ $searcher.FindAll <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionInGetEnumerator`

Comment: I'm curious - I assume your powershell.config on the systems where it won't work has something along the lines of the following; `<uri>
    <schemeSettings>
      <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
      <add name="https" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
    </schemeSettings>
  </uri>`.

Comment: If you copy the powershell binary as well as the config to say `powershell - Copy.exe` and `powershell - Copy.exe.config` in the same directory, remove the lines `<uri>`, `</uri>` and everything inbetween from `powershell - Copy.exe.config` you'd be able to run the DirectorySearcher if you start `powershell - Copy.exe`.

Comment: @nutjustme, I have checked the systems where it will not run(powershell ver2.0) and they do not have a `powershell.exe.config`, on my own system(powershell ver 5) it definitly has that file. What is the purpose of that file ? Are you saying that if I only copied those files accross I would not need to do the full powershell upgrade in order to be able to run powershell 5 ?

Comment: I got fooled trying it out on my own W10-box where I had the same errors. v2 didn't know of such a config option as the URI-bit so removing it solved the problem for me. I have no w7 or such to investigate at the moment.

Comment: @notjustme, are you saying you got it working on PS V2.0 ?

Comment: Running  -version 2.0 on Win10, yes.

Comment: @notjustme, I have successfully replicated your suggestion of copying the files and removed `<uri>, </uri> and everything inbetween`, no errors. Can you please tell me why there are no errors in that scenario ?