# powershell ver 2.0 search AD failure

Tags: powershell

I have raised a similar issue on Stackoverflow, however not been able to resolve.
The issue has been that we have mixed workstations using powershell version 5.x(win10) and 2.x(win7), I have had to make my powershell script backwards compatible with 2.x, this brings errors as shown below.
I cannot use Get-aduser as its not an option on powershell 2.x, I cannot install the module as this would make things to complex.

```
$Username = "xxx-xxxx"
$LdapFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$username))"
$User = (((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($Null, $LdapFilter)).FindOne()).GetDirectoryEntry())
$ext1 = $User.get("extensionAttribute1")
write-host `$ext1: $ext1
```

error message:

```
FindOne : Exception calling "FindOne" with "0" argument(s): "Configuration system failed to initialize"
At C:\gavin\AD_search.ps1:5 char:94
+ $User = (((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($Null, $LdapFilter)).FindOne <<<< ()).GetDirectoryEn
try())
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

get : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\gavin\AD_search.ps1:6 char:18
+ $ext1 = $User.get <<<< ("extensionAttribute1")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (get:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [query AD using powershell version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563500/query-ad-using-powershell-version-2)

Comment: The question doesn't have more information than the previous one. E.g. if the scripts works under PowerShell 2 (`PowerShell -version 2`) on the Windows 10 system, the script is generally correct and the Windows 7 machine could be simply disconnected from the domain.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/q/116304 for a correct example using `DirectoryServices`.

Comment: @iRon, The script fails on version 2 on windows 10 with the error displayed above, it does work with the modfications carried out to the config file under the same conditions, however the error message on the windows 10 is the same on the windows 7. I can confirm the windows 7 instance not connected from the domain as I am running this as a login script.